# Hackerrank 30 days of code day 6 java

Tags: java

> Task :
>   Given a string, S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line
>
> Input format:
>   The first line contains an integer, T (the number of test cases). 
>   Each line i of the T subsequent lines contains a string S.
>
> Constraint: 1<=T<=10
>                 2<=length of S <=10000

I tried executing but it doesn't pass the test case because it doesn't print in a single line. My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testcase = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i++)
    {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        char[] chararray = s.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < chararray.length; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(chararray[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j < chararray.length; j++)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(chararray[j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The output for the above code is:

> 2
>   HACKER
>   H
>   C
>   E
>
> A
>   K
>   R

How can I print the even and odd strings in a single line with 2 spaces separated?

Comment: As a hint, there's also a `System.out.print` method.

Comment: 1) build two strings. 2) print them with a space between them. Or use 2 passes.

Comment: Isn't Hackerrank something you're supposed to do *on your own*?
Voting to close and delete the question. This is cheating.

Comment: I am new to java. If i wanted to cheat there's already alot of resources available to copy and submit. But I want to check and fix  where i'm getting wrong.

Comment: hey ankita did my solution not work ? Let us know if you ran into any issues.

Comment: Hey thanks but It doesnt print in a single line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably better than previous:

```
private static void splitPrinter(String s) {
    StringBuilder sO = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder sE = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            sE.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            sO.append(s.charAt(i));        
        }
    }
    sE.append(" ");
    sE.append(sO.toString());
    System.out.println(sE.toString());
}
```

*edit.... thought it could be done easy with 1 string builder but then you have to worry about the length of the word being even or odd.

*edited again to remove extra spaces

Comment: Incorrect - you _should_ have two strings serparated by a space. You have many characters, each separated by a space.

Comment: well then it's even easier

Answer (score 1):

View full code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();

        in.nextLine();
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            String string = in.nextLine();
            char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                }
            }

            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0) 
                {
                    System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();

        in.nextLine();
        
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
            String string = in.nextLine();
            char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                }
            }

            System.out.print(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < charArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if (j % 2 != 0) 
                {
                    System.out.print(charArray[j]);
                }
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: iterating the string more than once :(. multiple system calls instead of 1 :(